# codeblocks auto-indent suddenly stops working (Windows 10)

Tags: c++, windows-10, codeblocks

All of a sudden, my codeblocks auto-indentation has stopped properly working.

This affects all previous programs, new programs - it is not code-specific.

I have tried all of the indentation settings on and off and in all sorts of combinations.

The actual error is that curly braces all line up with the beginning of the most indented code.

```
anyFunction()
{
    variables;
    for(int i(0); j<variable; i++){
        for(int j(0); j < 100; j++){
            code;
            }
            }
            }
```

**THIS IS NOT A MISSING ; OR ANY CODE-RELATED ISSUE.**

This error now happens in all codes.

Again, this is strange because it happened in the middle of coding, and I wasn't in any kind of settings when it did happen.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: don't know anything about codeblocks ,but have you tried giving anyFunction a return type ? Sometimes Formatting Tools get confused by syntax-errors (Intellisense in Visual Studio suffers sometimes from that).

Comment: Yeah, this happens in all codes for all functions, int, double, void, etc